# To make a dynamic dropdown with list of files in a directory using python-cgi

Tags: cgi, python-3.3

I am trying to retrieve file names with specified extension using cgi-python.Is there a way like in php.
I need to generate a dropdown list with the filenames(.txt) in a specific folder.
I am using python 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working with python 3.3.. Got the answer

```
print(' <select name="user">')
os.chdir("D:/users")
for files in os.listdir("."):
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
        print('<option value="D:/users/'+files+'">'+files.replace('.txt','')+'</option>')

print('</select> ')
```